# Is there a "multilayer" child selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to find every Child-node of an element thats in the n-th position, eg. in:

```
<span class="passive match" id="1"></span>
<ul>
    <li>
      <span class="active match"></span>
      <ul>
        <li>
           <span class="active match"></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<span class="passive match" id="2"></span>
<ul>
    <li>
      <span class="passive match"></span>
      <ul>
        <li>
           <span class="active"></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to find both "active match" li Child of the ul next to the span "passive match"

Something like:

```
span.passive.match + ul:'has-Child'(span.active.match) {CSS here}
```

But the corresponding span.active.match can be a 3rd/6th/9th/12th etc. child-element from "passive match". Is there a CSS-Selector that can handle this or do I need to write a jQuery-Script that does it (which would be inefficient I'd say as I would need a recursive function that may run across 10k+ elements)?

Basically i have a tree filled with folders (.passive) and data (.active) and i want to display every data thats matched with a given filter (.match) and its path but want to hide every folder that has no child thats matching the filter. So the span with id="2" should be hidden, while the id="1" should show up in my dom structure. As the tree is generated by a plugin with private function and is used in multiple situation i cant just edit/ overwrite it but have to either use the CSS-Selectors to hide the unnecessary objects or use a javascript-script to do so. Maybe you'll have a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

For this you need the [`:has()` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#relational)…

```
span.passive.match + ul:has(span.active.match)
```

… but it is not a standard (it is in draft status) and [no browser currently supports it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has).

---

In the meantime, alter your HTML so there is a class on the `ul`.

Ideally, do this when you generate the HTML, but you could modify it after the fact with JavaScript.

```js
$(".active.match").parents("ul").addClass("contains-active-match");
```

```css
span.passive.match + ul.contains-active-match {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="passive match" id="1">a</span>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="active match">b</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="active match">c</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<span class="passive match" id="2">d</span>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="passive match">e</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="active">f</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This wouldnt work if my active.match is the 6th/ 9th child tho, right?

Comment: @Grim — Why not?